# How to parse a method or any other valid expression using JavaParser

Tags: java, parsing, javaparser

[JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser) is a java source code parsing tool. I read the documents but found it only able to parse source of a full java class, like:

```
public class X {
    public void show(String id) {
        Question q = Quesiton.findById(id);
        aaa.BBB.render(q);
    }
}
```

But I want to parse only part of it, e.g. the method declaration:

```
public void show(String id) {
    Question q = Quesiton.findById(id);
    aaa.BBB.render(q);
}
```

How to do it or is it possible? If not, is there any other tool can do this?

---

**Update**

Actually I want to parse any valid expression in java, so I can do this easily with JavaParser:

```
CompilationUnit unit = JavaParser.parse(codeInputStream);

addField(unit, parseField("public String name"));  // not possible now
```

Comment: MethodVisitor does not serve your purpose? Please check the link  http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser  (Section -->Visiting class methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you can include the method in a dummy class and parse it as usual. For the example you provided, enclose it inside:

```
public class DUMMY_CLASS_FOO {

    // The string you're trying to parse (method or whatever)

}
```

Then you parse it as usual and neglect your dummy class while parsing.

**UPDATE:**

For the update you provided, you may try and catch

If the previous enclosure didn't do it, so enclose it into:

```
public class DUMMY_CLASS_FOO {

    public void DUMMY_METHOD_FOO {

        // Anything here

    }
}
```

You might also search for Access Level Modifiers (public, private, ...etc), and if found, do the 1st solution. If not found, do the other one.

Comment: This should work, but I also want to parse other java source code as `fields` or any other valid expression.

Comment: I updated my answer. If that helps, you can accept this answer, and if not, please let me know :)

Comment: I've checked the source of javaparser these 2 days, and found your solution maybe the only available one, except rewriting the parser.

Comment: It's a headache to rewrite the parser compared to a single check and a string concatenation.